# Spray Akka Json Unmarshalling

Tags: scala, akka, spray, spray-json, spray-routing

I've a problem about unmarshalling objects to Json via using spray - akka.

When i'd like to use actors that returns Future[List[Person]] , it doesn't work.

If i use dao object directly, it works.

Here are my codes:

**PersonDao.scala**

```
import scala.concurrent.ExecutionContext.Implicits.global
import scala.concurrent.Future

case class Person(id: Int, name: String, surname: String)

object PersonDao {

  def getAll: Future[List[Person]] = Future {
    List[Person](Person(1, "Bilal", "Alp"), Person(2, "Ahmet", "Alp"))
  }
}
```

**EntityServiceActor.scala**

```
import akka.actor.Actor
import com.bilalalp.akkakafka.model.PersonDao
import com.bilalalp.akkakafka.service.ServiceOperation.FIND_ALL

object ServiceOperation {

  case object FIND_ALL

}

class EntityServiceActor extends Actor {

  override def receive: Receive = {

    case FIND_ALL => PersonDao.getAll
  }
}
```

**ServerSupervisor.scala**

```
import akka.actor.{Actor, ActorRefFactory}
import com.bilalalp.akkakafka.webservice.TaskWebService
import spray.routing.RejectionHandler.Default


class ServerSupervisor extends Actor with PersonWebService {

  implicit val system = context.system

  override def receive: Receive = runRoute(entityServiceRoutes)

  override implicit def actorRefFactory: ActorRefFactory = context
}
```

**WebServiceTrait.scala**

```
import akka.util.Timeout

import spray.routing.HttpService

import scala.concurrent.duration._
import scala.language.postfixOps

import org.json4s.NoTypeHints
import org.json4s.native.Serialization._

trait WebServiceTrait extends HttpService {

  implicit def executionContext = actorRefFactory.dispatcher

  implicit val json4sFormats = formats(NoTypeHints)

  implicit val timeout = Timeout(120 seconds)
}
```

**PersonWebService.scala**

```
trait PersonWebService extends WebServiceTrait with Json4sSupport {

  val json3sFormats = DefaultFormats

  val entityServiceWorker = actorRefFactory.actorOf(Props[EntityServiceActor], "entityServiceActor")

  val entityServiceRoutes = {
    pathPrefix("person") {
      pathEndOrSingleSlash {
        get {
          ctx => ctx.complete((entityServiceWorker ? FIND_ALL).mapTo[Person])
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

**Application.scala**

```
import akka.actor.{ActorRef, ActorSystem, Props}
import akka.io.IO
import com.bilalalp.akkakafka.server.ServerSupervisor
import spray.can.Http


object Application extends App {

  implicit val system = ActorSystem("actorSystem")

  val mainHandler: ActorRef = system.actorOf(Props[ServerSupervisor])
  IO(Http)! Http.Bind(mainHandler, interface = Configuration.appInterface, port = Configuration.appPort)

}
```

When i run this code, It gives nothing and waits for a while.

After waiting browser gives this message:

> The server was not able to produce a timely response to your request.

And console output is

> [ERROR] [11/22/2015 21:15:24.109]
>   [actorSystem-akka.actor.default-dispatcher-7]
>   [akka.actor.ActorSystemImpl(actorSystem)] Error during processing of
>   request HttpRequest(GET,http://localhost:3001/person/,List(Host:
>   localhost:3001, Connection: keep-alive, Cache-C ontrol: no-cache,
>   Pragma: no-cache, User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.3; WOW64)
>   AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Maxthon/4.4.6.1000
>   Chrome/30.0.1599.101 Safari/537.36, DNT: 1, Accept-Encoding: gzip,
>   deflate, Accept-Language: tr-TR),Empty,HTTP/1.1)
>   akka.pattern.AskTimeoutException: Ask timed out on
>   [Actor[akka://actorSystem/user/$a/entityServiceActor#-1810673919]]
>   after [120000 ms]. Sender[null] sent message of type
>   "com.bilalalp.akkakafka.service.ServiceOperation$FIND_ALL$".
>           at akka.pattern.PromiseActorRef$$anonfun$1.apply$mcV$sp(AskSupport.scala:415)
>           at akka.actor.Scheduler$$anon$7.run(Scheduler.scala:132)
>           at scala.concurrent.Future$InternalCallbackExecutor$.unbatchedExecute(Future.scala:599)
>           at scala.concurrent.BatchingExecutor$class.execute(BatchingExecutor.scala:109)
>           at scala.concurrent.Future$InternalCallbackExecutor$.execute(Future.scala:597)

If i change PersonWebService.scala to this :

```
trait PersonWebService extends WebServiceTrait with Json4sSupport {

  val json3sFormats = DefaultFormats

  val entityServiceWorker = actorRefFactory.actorOf(Props[EntityServiceActor], "entityServiceActor")

  val entityServiceRoutes = {
    pathPrefix("person") {
      pathEndOrSingleSlash {
        get (
//                    ctx => ctx.complete((entityServiceWorker ? FIND_ALL).mapTo[Person])
          ctx => ctx.complete(PersonDao getAll)
        )
      }
    }
  }
}
```

It works and output is :

> [{"id":1,"name":"Bilal","surname":"Alp"},{"id":2,"name":"Ahmet","surname":"Alp"}]

I'd like to use actors in spray routes. I don't know whether it is a bad practice or not because i'm newbie in akka and spray.

How can i solve this? Any ideas?

Thank you.

Answer (score 4):

First of all, You can type (**PersonWebService.scala**):

```
pathEndOrSingleSlash {
    get {
      complete {
       (entityServiceWorker ? FindAll).mapTo[List[Person]]
    }
  }
```

And as @Timothy Kim said You need to send back results using "sender ! getAll.onComplete

As I an see getAll returns Future, so in my opinion best would be to resolve it in **EntityServiceActor.scala**:

```
// import the pipe pattern (see pipeTo below):
import akka.pattern.pipe
import context.dispatcher

override def receive: Receive = {
  case FindAll => 
    PersonDao.getAll()
      .recover({ case err => List() /* could log error here */ })
      .pipeTo(sender()) // do this instead of onComplete, it's safer
```

in this simple case getAll Future is resolved, if everything is ok, service will get list of persons, otherwise List will be empty.

Oh and another thing **PersonWebService.scala** should have **.mapTo[List[Person]]**

Comment: i did everything you said. It gives this error : java.lang.ClassCastException: Cannot cast scala.runtime.BoxedUnit to scala.collection.immutable.List
        at java.lang.Class.cast(Class.java:3369)

Comment: I improved the code snippet a bit, to use the best practices here - pipeTo as well as recovering in case of the futures failure

Answer (score 3):

You need to send a result back to sender:

```
case FIND_ALL =>
  PersonDao.getAll.pipeTo(sender())
```

Comment: While this code may answer the question, providing additional context regarding why and/or how this code answers the question improves its long-term value.

Comment: @Timothy Kim i've added this : case FIND_ALL => sender() ! PersonDao.getAll but it doesnt give any error but i can not see the json result. It returns this answer {} . What should i do?

Comment: `.mapTo[Person]` should be `.mapTo[List[Person]]` as already said above.

Comment: Almost, it should be .mapTo[Future[List[Person]]]